# Upgrade ravendb analyzer

Tags: ravendb, analyzer

I have a custom ravendb analyzer and I need to upgrade it to a newer version.

When I try and copy the new version into the analyzers folder I get an OS warning saying the file is in use.

I suppose this means that I need to stop raven, copy the file and restart it. But that would result in downtime as my db will obviously be offline during this time.

Is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Derek,
No, you have to do it this way.

Comment: Ok, that is disappointing. Any plans to make it possible? Ideally I would like to update my analyzers from my automated build, they don't change often but in the interest of scripting changes it would be useful.